# I want to find "Radiohead" but not "Radiohead's" with Sunspot/Solr

Tags: regex, solr, full-text-search, sunspot

I'm using solr via the sunspot gem in a rails project.

I am indexing scraped data.

My indexing is currently done like so:

```
searchable do
  text :title, :boost => 3.0 do
    title.gsub(/\'s\b/, "")
  end
  text :mentions do
    mentions.map do |mention|
      mention.title.gsub(/\'s\b/, "")
    end
  end
end
```

Currently, if I do:

```
Video.solr_search { fulltext '"Radiohead"' }
```

Solr will return results with:

```
Radiohead's
```

and

```
Radiohead
```

I would like to only find:

```
Radiohead
```

Is there a way to do this via Sunspot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what filters you have defined in the analyzer section of the field type for your field in `schema.xml` (in .../solr/conf directory). Here's an example:

```
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            ...
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
        </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

The behaviour you're seeing is called "stemming" - it's where the indexed value is the *stem* of the word, rather than the word itself. eg, "fly", "flies", "flew" and "flying" would all be indexed as "fly". If there's a filter like snowball (apache's stemmer), then you'll get the behaviour you're seeing. Try removing the filter, restarting solr then reindexing your documents.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info.  I will try this out tomorrow and report back.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a phrase query (using double quotes) :

```
Video.solr_search { fulltext '"Radiohead"' }.
```

Or modify you solr schema.xml so that you don't split "Radiohead's". I don't know your field configuration here so I can't provide more details...

Comment: My mistake, this is actually what I am doing, which is why I'm surprised it's not working.  Thanks for the response though.  I'll edit the question.